# finding the value of $Z+Z^{2}+Z^{3}........ $ if...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $ Z+Z^{-1} = 2 \cos 5$ then what's the value of $Z+Z^{2}+Z^{3}....
......Z^{63}$.
I wanted to to solve this with the value of $Z$. But may be the value of $Z$ is complex. Now it's quite impossible to me to solve this. please tell me how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}\tag1
$$
and
$$
e^{\pm i\theta}=\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta\tag2
$$
Hence
$$
\cos5^\circ=\frac{e^{5^\circ i}+e^{-5^\circ i}}{2}.\tag3
$$
Let $Z=e^{5^\circ i}$. Thus
\begin{align}
Z+Z^2+\cdots+Z^{63}&=\frac{Z(Z^{63}-1)}{Z-1}\\
&=\frac{Z^{63}-1}{\color{red}{\dfrac{Z-1}{Z}}}\\
&=\frac{Z^{63}-1}{1-Z^{-1}}\\
&=\frac{e^{315^\circ i}-1}{1-e^{-5^\circ i}}\\
&=\frac{\cos315^\circ+i\sin315^\circ-1}{1-\cos5^\circ+i\sin5^\circ}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sum_{r=1}^{63}z^r=\frac{z^{64}-1}{z-1}-1$$

Now solving for $z,z=\cos5\pm i\sin 5$

Apply $(\cos x+i\sin x)^n=\cos nx+i\sin nx$

Also $z-1=\cos5\pm i\sin 5-1=-2\sin^22.5\pm i2\sin2.5\cos2.5=\cdots$